# How to find people nearby and add both to conversation at the same time in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make an app chat that allow people to find stranger by distance, but i have no idea how to do this, only thing i know is show distance from two stranger using `Geolocator` , I'm very stuck and don't know what to do, I have no idea even though I've searched whole internet for few days. Two people from `firebase` database, and if they're both looking for stranger, and they are close to each other, bring them both into the conversation, like normal chat app for stranger, but with flutter, there are so little source to do this.

[image]
[image]

Please light me the way,  thank you a lot!

Comment: I highly recommend using an in-memory database such as Redis for this use-case. Not only does Redis have this functionality built into it but it will definitely out perform Firebase in this case. Now you will have to learn another technology, manage another layer etc.. But it will be totally worth it!

Comment: Firebase has two databases: Realtime Database, and Cloud Firestore. Solutions for geoquerying (that's the name of what you're trying to do) exist, but they're different. Which database are you using?

Comment: @AWebb thank for your comment, i will try it out today and feedback to you

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I plan to use realtime database, because I think a conversation between two strangers will happen while both are searching, but the data will be stored in the cloud database, but i don't know exactly how to make two stranger join a converstation at the same time

Comment: So what you are asking is that if two people are looking for a 'stranger' and they are within a certain radius of each other, they should both be automatically thrown into a conversation without asking them? Wouldn't it be better to notify them there are X number of strangers within their radius and prompt them to start a conversation. Then on the other end, notify the user they were invited to a conversation? Also you say you know how to *show distance from two stranger* which means you know the other person is there. What's preventing you from starting a conversation between them?

Comment: @Jay, yes, the main idea just like you said, because my main purpose is to show everyone as a "anonymous" so, they are the same, i mean, they will be choosen random in given range, like 10km have 1000 people, they will be choosen random, my problem is i don't know which tool to make they join together at the same time

Comment: Well, should be pretty straightforward. The app knows who the user is and randomly selects another user. All users have an observer on a node that is watching for their UID to be referenced. Then it will use a transaction to create a chat, or whatever the structure us, in Firebase containing both user uid's. The randomly selected user will know they were selected because they have an observer on the chats node, observing for their uid. Is there something more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package. I have used this to build real-time location-based image sharing before and it works really well

https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire

Comment: @Kamjab ayani thank you for the answer, but i stuck at how to join 2 people to a converstation at the same time by firebase

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to create a conversation/chat in Firebase, not how to locate other people.

Comment: you can use their both UID to make chatroomID , roomID = UID1 + UID2 , now since they are pointing to the same chat room they can send messages to each other.